# Error when checking target: Converting FC layers to Conv2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I was trying to replace the FC layers at the end of VGG 16 network with Convolutional layers. Below is my code:

```
model2= Sequential()
model2.add(Conv2D(4096, kernel_size=(8,8), activation="relu"))
model2.add(Conv2D(4096, kernel_size=(1,1), activation="relu"))
model2.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(1,1), activation="softmax"))

model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=inputshape)

F2model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model2(model.output))

for layer in F2model.layers[:25]:
   layer.trainable = False

F2model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(), loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

batch_size = 128
trainsize = 36000
validsize = 12000


F2model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=trainsize // batch_size,
    epochs=5,
    validation_data=valid_generator,
    validation_steps=validsize // batch_size,callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

I train the regular network with FC layers and that runs fine, but when I run the above, I get the below error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)in <module>
  4         epochs=5,
  5         validation_data=valid_generator,
  ----> 6         validation_steps=validsize // batch_size,callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])


ValueError: Error when checking target: expected sequential_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 16)
```

At this point I am trying to figure out where those dimensions(32,16) are coming from. ANy help would be appreciated. Thank you

### EDIT 1: For Full Traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-2702f38208c0> in <module>
      4         epochs=5,
      5         validation_data=valid_generator,
----> 6         validation_steps=validsize // batch_size,callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1730             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1731             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1732             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1733 
   1734     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    218                                             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    219                                             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 220                                             reset_metrics=False)
    221 
    222                 outs = to_list(outs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
   1506             x, y,
   1507             sample_weight=sample_weight,
-> 1508             class_weight=class_weight)
   1509         if self._uses_dynamic_learning_phase():
   1510             ins = x + y + sample_weights + [1]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    619                 feed_output_shapes,
    620                 check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 621                 exception_prefix='target')
    622 
    623             # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    133                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    134                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 135                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    136                 if not check_batch_axis:
    137                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_3 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 16)
```

Edit 2: Inputs Info:

```
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=traindf,directory="data_final",x_col="path",y_col="label",subset="training",batch_size=32,seed=42,shuffle=True,class_mode="categorical",target_size=(256,256))

valid_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=traindf,directory="data_final",x_col="path",y_col="label",subset="validation",batch_size=32,seed=42,shuffle=True,class_mode="categorical",target_size=(256,256))

if K.image_data_format()=="channels_first":
  inputshape=(3,imrows,imcols)
else:
  inputshape=(imrows,imcols,3)
```

Comment: post the full error Traceback

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionnal API of keras is better for this kind of problem :

```
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=inputshape)
x = model.output
x = Conv2D(4096, kernel_size=(8, 8), activation="relu")(x)
x = Conv2D(4096, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation="relu")(x)
out = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation="softmax")(x)

F2model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=out)


for layer in F2model.layers[:25]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Moreover i see that you are using binary_crossentropy with a softmax activation, this can lead to some problems:
- Use softmax and categorical_crossentropy
- Use sigmoid and binary_crossentropy

And becarefull with this model, using convolution of 4096 will make your number of parameters really really hudge !!

**(165 millions in this case)**

### EDIT

It looks like your problem only comes from your label array :

- Your last layer is a convolutional layer so it expect a 4D array with shape  `(batch_size, height, width, channel)` but your are giving to it an array of shape `(batch_size, 16)`
- So either change your last layer to be :

```py
out = Dense(16, activation="softmax")(x)
```

- Or change your label array to be acceptable to a convolutional layer.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, and thank you for your input. I ran you code(using functional API) but I'm still getting the same error regarding the columns.

Comment: Can you update your question with your inputs/labels shape plz ?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply. I added a Flatten layer just above the dense layer and the model worked. So dumb of me to have last layer as conv layer, Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Glad to have helped to you !